# Save Current View in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have several files open in a split view in the intelliJ IDEA.  Is there a way to save this setup (ie: which files are open and witch side of the split view they are on)?

I am hoping to work on some other aspects of the program for now, but will need to return to this view/setup periodically.

I have looked under `Window | Editor Tabs` but could not find anything there.

Comment: Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12130.

Comment: @CrazyCoder So, does that mean that this feature does not yet exist?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That is a shame. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by CrazyCoder in the comments, this feature does not yet exist in intelliJ. There is a related feature request here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12130